# MoveIt visualization of planned trajectories with attached objects

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an application where being able to visualize the trajectory before executing is beneficial for a number of reasons.  I recently added attached collision objects to the robot but they don't seem to show up in the trajectories visualized using move_group's `/move_group/display_planned_path` topic.  Is this the intended behavior?  If so, does anyone have suggestions on how to elegantly achieve what I am trying to get?

Somewhat related to http://answers.ros.org/question/248071/rviz-ignoring-collisions-between-attached-object-and-environment/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248105/moveit-visualization-of-planned-trajectories-with-attached-objects/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There exists an issue for this in the moveit repository: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/190
Although this is talking about the visualized trail, the underlying issue is the same.

So, currently the attached objects are not visualized there, but a patch to change that is welcome upstream!

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2016-11-15**:
Thanks for the pointer v4hn.  I'll see if I can't find some time to implement this...